# Why does aggregate work when using SessionWindows in Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I've tested the simple code using SessionWindows in Kafka Streams.
(Spring Cloud Stream version : Elmhurst.SR1, kafka version : 1.0.1.)

```
@EnableBinding(StreamTestChanel.class)
public class MyKafkaStreamsTest {
   private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

   @Value("${window.session.gapSeconds:5}")
   private long gapSeconds;
   @Value("${window.session.durationSeconds:20}")
   private long durationSeconds;

   private SessionWindows sessionWindows = SessionWindows.with(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(gapSeconds)).until(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(durationSeconds));

   @StreamListener(StreamTestChanel.CHANEL_INPUT)
   public void process(KStream<String, MyLog> input) {

       input
            .groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(sessionWindows)
            .count() // aggregation
            .toStream() // KTable to KStream
            .foreach((key, count) -> {
                logger.debug("## start --> window time : [{}] - [{}], key : {}({})", DateFormatUtils.format(key.window().start(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"), DateFormatUtils.format(key.window().end(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"), key.key(), count);
            });
   }
}
```

After testing, the log is left as below.

```
2018-11-14 17:22:29 [DEBUG](MyKafkaStreamsTest.java:52) ## start --> window time : [2018-11-14 17:22:24.396] - [2018-11-14 17:22:28.866], key : test15(75)
2018-11-14 17:22:34 [DEBUG](MyKafkaStreamsTest.java:52) ## start --> window time : [2018-11-14 17:22:24.396] - [2018-11-14 17:22:28.866], key : test15(null)
2018-11-14 17:22:44 [DEBUG](MyKafkaStreamsTest.java:52) ## start --> window time : [2018-11-14 17:22:24.421] - [2018-11-14 17:22:38.979], key : test06(null)
2018-11-14 17:22:44 [DEBUG](MyKafkaStreamsTest.java:52) ## start --> window time : [2018-11-14 17:22:24.421] - [2018-11-14 17:22:40.103], key : test06(165)
2018-11-14 17:22:44 [DEBUG](MyKafkaStreamsTest.java:52) ## start --> window time : [2018-11-14 17:22:24.438] - [2018-11-14 17:22:38.992], key : test01(null)
2018-11-14 17:22:45 [DEBUG](MyKafkaStreamsTest.java:52) ## start --> window time : [2018-11-14 17:22:24.438] - [2018-11-14 17:22:42.256], key : test01(165)
```

https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#session-windows

I read this but I don't know why the count value is null and the window's start and end times overlap.
Is there something I've done wrong?

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If two session windows are merged, first a new merged window is created and afterward the old two windows are deleted. The `null`s you are seeing are those deletes.

**Update:**

As of Kafka 2.1.0, the `suppress()` operator is available that allows you to suppress intermediate updates and only emit a single final result per window. *Hint*: in 2.1.0, `suppress()` has some bugs, and it's recommended to use `2.3.1` release for `suppress()` to make sure it's working correctly :)

Comment: I do not know if this is possible ... Is there a way to see only the final merged window?

Comment: Not really. Kafka Streams processing mode is continuous updates to provide minimal latency. But if you know the maximum "lateness" of data, you can just wait until this time passed, and consider existing windows with `end-timestamp - gap < current-time - max_lateness" as those won't be update any more and thus are final.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I believe we can use Supress() method to avoid emitting intermediate results. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, that sound correct. I assume that I put this answer before `suppress()` was added to Kafka Streams :)